# python reading sql db encoding error at /python2.7/json/encoder.py

Tags: python, mysql, json, encoding

I'm trying to run a sql query through python and im getting this error:

```
2017-01-26 15:46:33,173:INFO:root:Running query:
SELECT id, tweet_id, screen_name, created_at, text, lat,
                                                    lon
FROM twitter.twitter LIMIT 100
2017-01-26 15:46:33,260:ERROR:root:'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 139: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/views.py", line 2500, in sql_json
    data = sql_lab.get_sql_results(query_id, return_results=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/local.py", line 188, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 420, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/sql_lab.py", line 173, in get_sql_results
    payload = json.dumps(payload, default=utils.json_iso_dttm_ser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 139: invalid start byte
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that one column containing special characters was causing the problem. So I changed its Collation to a BLOB "most forgiving data type". Now works fine

Answer (score 0):

Tell python that the source is latin1 instead of utf8; see if that helps.

What were you expecting?  In `CHARACTER SET latin1`, hex 85 is `…`.